# Как дождаться выполения setInterval, и вернуть результат функции fn1, переменную number, котороая в конце должна хранить в себе цифру 5?

Tags: javascript

```js
function fn1() {
  let number = 0;
  let x1 = setInterval(fn2, 1000);
  let x2 = setInterval(fn2, 2000);

  function fn2() {
    ++number;
    console.log("number =", number);
    if (number >= 5) {
      clearInterval(x1);
      clearInterval(x2);
    }
  }
  return number;
}

let result = fn1();
console.log("result =", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fn1() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {

    let number = 0;
    let x1 = setInterval(fn2, 1000);
    let x2 = setInterval(fn2, 2000);

    function fn2() {
      ++number;
      console.log("number =", number);
      if (number >= 5) {
        clearInterval(x1);
        clearInterval(x2);
        resolve(number);
      }
    }
  })
}

fn1().then(result => {
  console.log("result =", result)
})
```

А вообще, см. предлагаемый [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/) вопроса. :)